# How to handle or close a reset password form popup modal which is coming from User Email?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, bootstrap-modal

I have a User password reset form with popup modal, which is coming from a "forgot password" email link. When I try to close the popup model, it doesn't close, but the password link was generated using devise gem. Any advice on how to close this and can I do this with the help of JavaScript?

Here is my reset form code:

```
app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb.

 <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content pad_bottom_15">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close fa fa-close modal-close" 
                    enter code heredata-dismiss="modal">
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid pad_lft_ryt_30">
      <span class="model_heading">Chang your password!</span>

      <br>

    <div class="form-group" id= "users-reset-password">
        <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: 
      password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>

       <%= f.error_notification %>

        <%= f.input :reset_password_token, as: :hidden %>
        <%= f.full_error :reset_password_token %>


      <div class="">
      <%= f.input :password, label: "New password", required: true, 
         autofocus: true, hint: ("(#{@minimum_password_length} 
             characters minimum)" if @minimum_password_length) %>
      </div>

      <div class="">
            <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label: "Confirm your 
              new password", required: true %>               
      </div>


      <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn login_btn btn-sm">Reset 
                                your password</button>
      </div>

      <% end %>
            </div>
     <!--<span class="no_profile modhide" id="sign_up_link">Don't      
              have   a profile? <%#= link_to "Create one now.",  
              sign_up_modal_page_index_path, remote: true %></span>-->
  </div>
    <p> Questions? <a href="mailto:info@xyz.com",        
             class="model_a">info@xyz.com </a></p>enter code here
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried different properties of the modal, but none of them are working for me.

Comment: If you have this form in a modal, you can use jQuery to close the modal. `$(modal-selector).modal('hide')`

Comment: what you said is correct. But  here  popup modal is coming from forgot password link. so when i tried to close popup, it's not closing. It behaves like a static page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery hide property, we can close this modal.

```
 $(function () {
    $('#modal').modal('hide');
 });
```

Now my JQuery knowledge got improved.